# Merge Raster Layers with Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, merge, raster-calculator

I am looking to merge three raster layers together, we are only allowed to use the Raster Calculator tool in Spatial Analyst, ArcToolBox.

Using ArcMap 10.2

Comment: Welcome to the GIS.SE! Can you give us a little more detail? For example, in what way are you looking to 'merge' the rasters? Are you looking to find the minimum of the three? To sum them? To divide one by another and then add the third? Map algebra allows for a really wide range of options for combining raster data.

Comment: To add to @WhiteboxDev list could you also mean "stack" the 3 rasters into a single dataset?